# Question on proving !A & B || A & !B = A XOR B

Tags: boolean-algebra

I do apologise if this question has been asked before, but I am having trouble trying to get from `!A & B || A & !B` to `A XOR B`.

I've tried doing it in reverse by starting with `A XOR B` (`(A || B) & !(A & B)`), and I reached `(A || B) & (!A || !B)` and `!((!A & !B) || (A & B))` using 2 different paths, and I know that the results of the 2 paths are the same because of the de morgan's law, yet I just can't figure out how to get to `!A & B || A & !B`.

EDIT: Just thought I'd explain my use of symbols. I'm not familiar with MathJax, and while I could use the proper symbols of ¬, ∧, ∨, it's just easier for me to type !, &, ||.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use notations you used for your comfort..These are used in programming, not on logics and mathematics (as far as I know).

We will start from `A XOR B = (A || B) && (!A || !B)` which you have already found. The trick is to add terms such as `(A || !A)` where it does not change value of logic.

`(A || B) && (!A || !B) = ((A || B) && (!B || B)) && ((!A || !B) && (!A || A))`

For the first term, `((A || B) && (!B || B)) = (A && !B) || B`.

For the second term, `((!A || !B) && (!A || A)) = !A || (!B && A)`.

Combining these two gives `((A && !B) || B) && ((A && !B) || !A)`. By simple boolean algebra you may see this is equal to `(A && !B) || (B && !A)`, which you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but I also realised I could just use the distributive law by expanding:

`(A || B) && (!A || !B)`

`((A || B) && !A) || ((A || B) && !B)`

`!A & A || !A & B || !B & A || !B & B`

then complement law and identity law:

`FALSE || !A & B || !B & A || FALSE`

`!A & B || !B & A`

However, I marked Gratus's solution as the accepted answer as it actually encouraged me to think about how to add terms without changing the value.